# Forward to wrong magento store

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9.1

This is my code in the index.php of Magento to switch the Store:

```html
if ($url['host'] === 'five-oaks-int.eu') {
    if ($geoplugin->countryCode === 'CH') {
        header('Location: http://schweiz.five-oaks-int.eu');
        exit;
    }

    Mage::run('five_oaks_german', 'store' );
} else {
    Mage::run('default', 'store');
}
```

If i call the url `five-oaks-int.eu` magento loads not the store `five_oaks_german` but the default store. The url in browser change to url of the default store.

Why shows magento not call the `five_oaks_german`?
The store settings the url seems to be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you post the output of `$url`?

The best way of doing this though is to use the `MAGE_RUN_CODE` and set it in the vhost (if you're using Apache) or use 'map' if you're using Nginx.

In Apache you can do this using .htaccess if you don't have access to the vhost:

`SetEnvIf Host .*five-oaks-int.eu.* MAGE_RUN_CODE=five_oaks_german`

Taken from: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/multi-site/ms_apache.html

If you're on Nginx then you can use the 'map' - see http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/multi-site/ms_nginx.html